# angularjs: $http is not defined in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have 3 files:

*app.js*

```
angular.module("starweb", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"])
       .config(function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider  ....
```

*addHostingController.js*

```
  angular.module("starweb")
  .controller("addHostingCtrl", function ($scope, domainService) {
        $scope.data.domains = domainService.getDomain();
}
```

*domainService.js*

```
angular.module("starweb")
.constant("domainList", "http://localhost:15536/api/product/xxxx")
.service("domainService", function ($http, $q,domainList) {
    return ({
        getDomain: GetDomains()
    });
});

function GetDomains() {
    $http.get(domainList).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
```

On the page source, all 3 files are included (*app.js* first). Chrome shows `$http is undefined`, what's wrong with my setup ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetDomains` function does not have access to the `domainService` scope, where you have injected the `$http` service.

You should change your code to something like this :

```
.service("domainService", function ($http, $q, domainList) {
  return {
    getDomain: function (handleSuccess, handleError) {
      $http.get(domainList).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
    }
  };
});
```

You should also define the `handleSuccess` and the `handleError` callbacks, surely as parameters of your `getDomain` function.

Comment: $http get is a promise. You should return the promise, not map it to function delegates